# ERA runway close NOTAM

Tags: flight-planning

***In the Flight Planning Stage***

If enroute alternate airport runway close NOTAM isuue and its only the airport which in 60min circle on the flight route,
Should we find othere flight route or planning EDTO flight plan?

I think ERA is adequate airport. In case of an emergency, the ERA can be used regardless of the runway close NOTAM. So it not necessary to change flight route or EDTO.

What do you think about this ?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Because it looks like it.

Comment: Do you mean that you planned to use a single-runway airport as your alternate, but that _during this flight_ a NOTAM was issued closing the runway, therefore leaving you without an alternate? Please [edit] your question to be more clear.

Comment: @GdD Or there may be machinery on the runway that makes landing there more dangerous than off-field.

Answer (score 2):

If the only runway is closed, you should not (and cannot legally) use the airport as an alternate. If a usable runway is open at the airport, you can use the airport as an alternate.

Besides the rules, it may not be physically possible to use a closed runway because of equipment, partial or no pavement, water, etc., so it makes no sense to use it as an alternate.

Comment: I agree that if the only runway is notam'd closed you should not use it as a required alternate. But when you say it is not legal, what regulation are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

An airport with no open runway is not an alternative as there's nowhere to land on it, so no it cannot be used for flight planning.

The runway may not exist if it is notamed closed, as it could be having pavement work going on. The taxiways may be clogged up with heavy equipment. A closed runway may mean a closed airport with no navaids, lights, emergency services, etc. If you landed there you may not even be able to leave the airport.

A closed airport along your route may be useful in an emergency, if you have no engine it's probably better than a field.